# Erasing an equal_range iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, equal-range

I've got a pair of iterators:

```
pair <multimap<CFile,Filetype>::iterator, multimap<CFile,Filetype>::iterator> range;
range = m_DirectoryMap.equal_range(obj);
```

That pair holds duplicated elements in a MultiMap - e.g. there is 1 object that has 2 more duplicates (so basically 3 objects) and I need to remove 2 of them, so only 1 is left.

I was doing this by a simple while loop, like this:

```
auto it = range.first;
++it;
while (it != range.second)
        it = m_DirectoryMap.erase(it);
```

After that, only 1 object was left - which is my goal.
Later I have found that I should probably try and erase the whole pair by 1 function call and there shouldn't be any needs for loops, like this:

```
m_DirectoryMap.erase(range.first, range.second);
```

This seems more cleaner, but the problem is that it removes all objects.

Then I tried:

```
m_DirectoryMap.erase(++range.first, range.second);
```

This seems to leave the first object and remove the rest, so it is working for me, but my question is - is this the right way to do, what I'm looking for?

Comment: Yes, it's right if you are sure there is at least one element with that key in the container. If not, you should check `range.first != range.second` before incrementing it, otherwise you create an invalid range.

Comment: Oh, right. I didn't think about that. Thanks again, Jonathan Wakely. :)